# How to make Dynamic height items on GridView by Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview, staggered-gridview

I would like to implement like this pic on Flutter.

[image]

I'm trying to implement like this code using SliverStaggeredGrud.count.
However, When I enter long text, the add button was moved to next Column.

```
 return SliverStaggeredGrid.count(
                crossAxisCount: 3,
                mainAxisSpacing: 16.0,
                children: userItems,
                staggeredTiles: userItems
                    .map<StaggeredTile>((_) => const StaggeredTile.fit(1))
                    .toList(),
              );
```

Please help it.

V/r

Comment: Can you include your `userItems` code as well?